# NodeJS web applocation loading issue

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a nodejs application at https://intro.dexfin.com, it was working fine for long time. But from few days back it has this loading issue. It loads and then the goes blank. I have tried it both on Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 16.04. Recompiled on both the platforms, and then deployed to apache server. Even if it run it with "npm -server build", the problem persists.

Nodejs Version: v12.10.0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is impossible to help you unless you provide a lot more information and also most importantly some code. Also if the app works on your localhost and worked on a server before it might have nothing to do with node.js but rather the server it runs on. Maybe an update of node.js, apache etc.? **EDIT** just tried the link an the app actualy loads and then due to some error it disappears. I'm seeing an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ticker' of undefined` in file `Table.js`

Comment: Hi, thanks. here is the code. As far as I remember there were no updates...

Comment: Hi @RishabhShukla, one of the primary reasons for it to not work is - the API: https://exchange.dexfin.com/api/v2/peatio/public/markets/tickers has no property `ethusdt`. Once you get that corredted, you'd need to be a bit more careful with the checks added. Once they are done - the app seems to work as expected

Comment: Hi thanks @iyerrama29, I was able to resolve the issue very easily after you pointed out the issue. I really apprecaite your help, god bless you.